# Issue with building App Engine Endpoint Module on Android Studio (Maven)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

I'm trying to generate App Engine Endpoints on Android Studio but Maven is giving the following error:

http://pastebin.com/Z8R00AJb

Would anyone know how to resolve it? Maven initially was giving me errors that it couldn't find it so I installed 3.1.0 and added M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME but those didn't work either so I had to go into settings of Android Studio and point to the directory where I extracted maven.

Thanks

EDIT:
I changed the version of Maven to 3.0.5. Apparently 3.1.X is compatible with the app-engine maven plugin as stated here: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the version of Maven to 3.0.5. Apparently 3.1.X is compatible with the app-engine maven plugin as stated here: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=31.